# How can produce a list/report that shows which Profiles have access to an App?

Tags: security, profile

I am attempting to see which Profiles (or more specifically which Roles) have access to an App. I can see this by going into each individual Profile and checking their Custom App Settings section of a Profile, but I would rather have a list showing me which Profiles have a specific App checked as Visible without going into each individual one.

Is there a way to do this ? I saw that somebody referred to PermComparator for this, but that is not the right solution because it only allows you to check several Profiles at a time. It's not an ideal solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than going to the profile, you can go to your custom app and click "edit", and it will list the profile visibility.

[image: Setup-Create-Apps App edit screen]

As for which roles have access, what you can do (Read/Create/Edit/Delete) is controlled by the profile, and which records of those objects you can see, is controlled by role.  The app access doesn't relate to a users role, so some users in a role may see the app when others do not. You can see which users have access by looking at the users assigned to the profiles with access.